# omniauth - is there any reason why I should store the OAuth2 token in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, omniauth

So, I'm just starting to use omniauth and have gotten it working with facebook. I have set it up so that it automatically redirects back to facebook for a new token when the current token expires. Based upon that, is there any reason why I should be storing the token to the db? I currently log user accesses but don't really see any value in logging the token. Would appreciate any ideas on why I should.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your business logic. For example, do you need to access the user's Facebook details at a later time, even when he is logged out? Or if you are queuing tasks (i.e. running this in the background), do you need to post to his wall a few hours later, instead of this very instant?

Another reason I can think of, is. Do you require your app to obtain a new token via Facebook all the time when the user needs to interact to Facebook via your app? Or would you like to store these tokens in your app, so the user does not need to go through the same process over and over?

It all depends on the kind of user experience you are trying to deliver.